# Why is matplotlib's plt.draw() not updating xticklabels?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to modify my xticklabels before plotting, but plt.draw() does not seem to update the values.  How can I get these values updated prior to plotting with plt.show()?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
num_bins = 50
x = 100 + 15 * np.random.randn(10000)
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_ylabel('Number')
ax.set_xlabel('Distance')
ax.set_title('Distance vs. Number')
# Draw the canvas, otherwise the labels won't be positioned and have values
ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.draw()
# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
for xl in ax.get_xticklabels(): print xl # Values not set
plt.show()
for xl in ax.get_xticklabels(): print xl # Values set
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `plt.draw()` to achieve the desired outcome.
The labels are in fact updated beofre you plot them - so your figure shows the intent. However, reading the correct labels from the axis does not work until after the plot was created.

Consider this example (add a line to assign only two xticks and labels):

```
plt.xticks([20,135],['one', 'two'])
for xl in ax.get_xticklabels(): print xl # Values not set
plt.show()
for xl in ax.get_xticklabels(): print xl # Values set
```

The output you see is:

1. ```
   Text(0,0,u'one')
   Text(0,0,u'two')
   ```
2. This plot opens:
   [image: changed labels histogram]
3. ```
   Text(20,0,u'one')
   Text(135,0,u'two')
   ```

The actual location - though assigned - cannot be read from the plot before it was created.

---

This plot was created without the following lines of code from your example:

```
ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.draw()
```